# MySQL - trigger-order PRECEDES not recognized

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried this from the MySQL site and got an error; it seems that the trigger-order `PRECEDES` is not recognized.

Is there something I have to set somewhere? I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_transaction 
BEFORE INSERT ON account
FOR EACH ROW PRECEDES ins_sum
    SET
        @deposits = @deposits + IF(NEW.amount>0,NEW.amount,0),
        @withdrawals = @withdrawals + IF(NEW.amount<0,-NEW.amount,0);
```

> #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'ins_sum

I have MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64) that comes with the latest version of xampp.

Thank you!

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Trigger order was added in 5.7.

Comment: Note thst `MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB` specifies only the *client* (CLI) software version.  `SELECT @@VERSION, @@VERSION_COMMENT;` for the actual server version.

Comment: Well, 10.1.38-MariaDB is the actual server version as per SELECT @@VERSION.